# Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'dll' because it is being used by another process

Tags: .net, powershell, iis, web-deployment

I have a script to copy all artifact dotnet to remote server (from Jenkins server to IIS folder on remote server) for Deploy Stage like below:

```
#Parameters
param($userName, $passWord, $serverName, $deployFolder, $destinationFolder, $iisName)

$passwd = ConvertTo-SecureString $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $passwd

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName -Credential $creds

#Stop IIS Application
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Import-Module IISAdministration; Stop-Website $args[0];}  -ArgumentList $iisName

Start-Sleep -s 200

#Copy new build to deploy folder
Copy-Item -Recurse -Force -Path $deployFolder -Destination $destinationFolder -ToSession $session

#Start IIS Application
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock { Import-Module IISAdministration; Start-Website $args[0];}  -ArgumentList $iisName
```

But sometimes I got issue `Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'dll' because it is being  used by another process.`

Any ideas? Please let me know!
Thanks

Comment: Well, you probably know already why. Why did you add the `Start-Sleep` cmdlet? How do you assert that your web service is no longer running when replacing its files?

Comment: Use Robocopy to copy the files, it has built-in retry logic. It's no use trying to test if file is locked before copying, as that's prone to race conditions.

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure how to stop all files of my web service before copy. So I used the Sleep cmdlet. I know this way is not good. But I don't know any way to do this. Sometimes this issue still happens.

Comment: If you want to stop web service, you can [stop website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/stop-website?view=winserver2012-ps) and [stop app pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/stop-webapppool?view=winserver2012-ps) so that dll will not be used by another process.

Comment: @BruceZhang As my script, I stopped web service before copy `Import-Module IISAdministration; Stop-Website $args[0];`. But sometimes dll files still in another process.

Comment: In addition to the website, the application pool also needs to be stopped, and the application pool will preload the application cache to the local.

Comment: Thanks so much, @BruceZhang. Let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments of Bruce Zhang, I add [stop app pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadminstration/stop-webapppool?view=winserver2012-ps) to my script. It works. 
`Stop-WebAppPool -Name $args[0];`